# How Can I Make a Fluid Button

Tags: css

I have a submit button I'm using in a form. The long text is normally fine but causes problems when viewed on a small screen.

Currently the button stays the same width, regardless of page width, and causes the page to scroll horizontally if its too narrow.

I'd like the text to wrap like it was inside an inline-block element. I've specified that in the css, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
input{background:#deaded;padding:10px 30px;display:inline-block;border-radius:5px}

<input type="submit" value="This is where the slogan goes" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `white-space: normal;`.

```css
input {
  background: #deaded;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="This is where the slogan goes" />
```